# How can I prove if this is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Given

$\left< f,g \right> =\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ f'(t)g(t)dt } \quad in\quad C\left[ 0,1 \right] $

How can I prove if this is (or not) an inner product on the given vector space?

Comment: Check the [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

Comment: I think the real tipoff for this one is that this "inner product" isn't even defined for all $f,g \in C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Consider a nonzero constant function $f$ and compute $\langle f,f\rangle$.

Comment: So, for example, if f=1,

$\int _{ 0 }^{ 1 }{ 0\cdot 1dt=0 } $

Right?

Thanks a lot! Now I see it was a silly question, but i'm not used to this

Comment: I could not see the problem as the calculation of the inner product  is 1 with me, and also why $C_{2}[0,1]$  is an inner product space with the inner product defined by $$<f,g> = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\bar g(x) dx$$, what is the difference?