# why $C_{2}[a,b]$ is an inner product space under the given inner product, while $C[a,b]$ is not?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, inner-products

I could not see the problem here [How can I prove if this is an inner product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164460/how-can-i-prove-if-this-is-an-inner-product) as the calculation of the inner product is 1 with me, and also why $C_{2}[0,1]$ is an inner product space with the inner product defined by
$<f,g>=∫_{0}^{1}f(x)\bar g(x)dx$

, what is the difference?

Comment: The inner product in the linked case has the derivative of $f$ under the integral. So if $f\equiv 1$ then $\langle f,f\rangle = \int_0^1 f'(x) f(x) dx = \int_0^1 0 \times 1 d x = 0$. $C[0,1]$ would be an inner product space with the inner product that you describe.

Comment: @TrevorNorton  I thought it is the conjugate not the derivative ....... hahaha

Comment: Yeah, I can see how that could be confusing lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linear space $C[a,b]$ of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ *is* an inner product space under $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt$. The only property in question is whether $\langle f,f\rangle =0$ iff $f=0$. But this property follows easily from the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. For suppose
$$
   \int_{0}^{1}|f(t)|^2dt = 0.
$$
Then $\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt=0$ for all $0 \le x \le 1$ because
$$
 0 \le \int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt \le \int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt + \int_{x}^{1}|f(t)|^2dt = \int_{0}^{1}|(f)|^2dt = 0.
$$
$|f(t)|^2$ is continuous because $f$ is. Hence, $0=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}|f(t)|^2dt=|f(x)|^2$ for all $x$.

The linear space $C_2[0,1]$ is also an inner product space under the same inner product.

Note that neither space is a Hilbert space; the completion of either space is $L^2[0,1]$.

Comment: Is the there is a link for the proof that $L^2[0,1]$ is complete on this site?

Comment: @Idonotknow  $L^2$ consists of equivalence classes of Lebesgue measurable, square integrable functions on $[0,1]$, grouped by the equivalence relation that the functions are equal a.e. with respect to Lebesgue measure. There should be a proof in most Functional Analysis texts.

Answer (score -1):

The normed space is an inner product space if and only if the parallelogram law holds. This is Jordan-von Neumann Theorem (1937). Check whether or not the parallelogram law holds in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I know that it does not hold ..... it is written in Kreyszig ..... but why the other space is an inner product ?

Comment: Because in $L_2$ (yes, the notation should be like that, we consider the functions integrable with a square) all the axioms are fulfilled. For instance, let $\langle f,f\rangle=0$. Then $\int_0^1 |f|^2 dx=0$ which means that $f=0$ almost everywhere. This is OK since $L_2$ is a space of equivelence clesses of functions equal almost everywhere. Try to check the remaining axioms.

Comment: But the other space is $C_{2}$ not $L_{2}$, what is the relation between them? ... what is the space $C_{2}$?